# Mechanic of how observing function works in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I believe everyone is familiar with

```
open func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView)
```

This function is called whenever a new subView is added to the UIView.

I am wondering on how to achieve? Like, what is the underlying codes to achieve this?

Thanks

Edit:

what i mean in the question is the codes to achieve a non-objective-c observing function. For example, we can build a notification, so that whenever addSubView is called, the didAddSuView is called correspondently, but apparently, in this case. It is not an object-c selector which we see in normal implementation. So i am asking how do we achieve something like this, which means, how do i trigger a function when another function is called without it being an objc function.

Btw, just to clarify further. The function is implemented as function of UIView (Extension UIView), so it is not a protocol, which means it wasn't  elegantly achieved as delegate.

So again, i am asking.. How can i replicate something like this?

Comment: May i know why this question is down voted?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `didAddSubview`? *"The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses can override it to perform additional actions when subviews are added. This method is called in response to adding a subview using any of the relevant view methods."*. Please clarify your question. What part of that do you not understand?

Comment: I'm about to downvote this because It doesn't really say what issue you are facing. *"...how to achieve"*? *"...what is the underlying code"*? I apologize if the only thing going on here is a language/culture barrier, but what *are* you trying to achieve specifically speaking? I'd be happy to try to answer - but it's hard without know *more exactly* what you are asking. (One line of code is likely the reason for my confusion.)

Comment: @rmaddy what i mean in the question is the codes to achieve a non-objective-c observing function. For example, we can build a notification, so that whenever addSubView is called, the didAddSuView is called correspondently, but apparent, in this case. It is not an object-c selector which we see in normal implementation. So i am asking how do we achieve something like this, which means, how do i trigger a function when another function is called without it being a objc function.

Comment: @dfd pls read my comment as well

Comment: But this is just about subclassing, why would it need to be marked as objc ? Pretty basic stuff, method exists in superclass so it can be called for the superclass and any subclass that overrides it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“The underlying codes” is that you just call the “observing function” when it needs to be called. There's no magic in how UIKit calls `didAddSubview`. It doesn't use any features specific to Objective-C.

The iOS SDK has four methods for adding a subview to a view:

- `addSubview:`
- `insertSubview:atIndex:`
- `insertSubview:aboveSubview:`
- `insertSubview:belowSubview:`

All of these methods are wrappers for a private method, `_addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:`. You can check this using a disassembler, or by putting a breakpoint in `didAddSubview:` and looking at the stack trace to see who calls it.

The private method calls `[self didAddSubview:subview]` using a normal Objective-C message. It does not “build a notification”. The source code probably looks something like this:

```
- (void)_addSubview:(UIView *)newSubview position:(UIViewSubviewPosition)position relativeTo:(UIView *)sibling {
    // Lots of bookkeeping related to first responder status,
    // gesture recognizers, auto layout, visual effects,
    // and private implementation details…

    [newSubview removeFromSuperview];

    switch (position) {
        case UIViewSubviewPositionAtEnd:
            [self.layer addSublayer:newSubview.layer];
            break
        case UIViewSubviewPositionBelowSibling:
            [self.layer insertSublayer:newSubview.layer below:sibling.layer];
            break;
        case UIViewSubviewPositionAboveSibling:
            [self.layer insertSublayer:newSubview.layer above:sibling.layer];
            break;
        default:
            [self.layer insertSublayer:newSubview.layer atIndex:(unsigned int)position];
            break;
    }

    [newSubview didMoveToSuperview];
    [newSubview didMoveToWindow];
    [self didAddSubview:newSubview];

    // Lots more bookkeeping related to first responder status,
    // gesture recognizers, auto layout, visual effects,
    // and private implementation details…
}
```

In Swift, it could look like this:

```
enum SubviewPosition {
    case atEnd
    case below(UIView)
    case above(UIView)
    case atIndex(UInt32)
}

func _addSubview(_ newSubview: UIView, position: SubviewPosition) {
    // Lots of bookkeeping related to first responder status,
    // gesture recognizers, auto layout, visual effects,
    // and private implementation details…

    newSubview.removeFromSuperview()

    switch position {
        case .atEnd: layer.addSublayer(newSubview.layer)
        case .below(let sibling):
            layer.insertSublayer(newSubview.layer, below:sibling.layer)
        case .above(let sibling)):
            layer.insertSublayer(newSubview.layer, above:sibling.layer)
        case .atIndex(let index):
            layer.insertSublayer(newSubview.layer at:index)
    }

    newSubview.didMoveToSuperview()
    newSubview.didMoveToWindow()
    didAddSubview(newSubview)

    // Lots more bookkeeping related to first responder status,
    // gesture recognizers, auto layout, visual effects,
    // and private implementation details…
}
```